# How to insert fields from one file into fields of another file at particular location?

Tags: text-processing

Is there any quick way to inserts fields from one file into another.

For example, if the file contents of file1 and file 2 are like this :

```
File1:
=======
size1
size2
size3

File2:
=======
char fname[];
char lname[];
char address[];
```

Is it possible to make file 2 look like this quickly?

```
File2:
=========
char fname[size1];
char lname[size2];
char address[size3];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and dirty

```
awk -F\[ 'NR==FNR { s[NR]=$1 ; } NR > FNR { printf "%s[%s%s\n",$1,s[FNR],$2 ;}'
```

where

- `-F\[` tell awk to use [ as separator
- if in first file `(NR==FNR)`, record line (using position in file as index)
- next file, print two field, and recorded value.

Comment: +1: wow, and thank you , exactly what I was looking for :)